# What episode do Gintoki and Hijikata fight in a roof?

Tags: gintama

I recently stumbled upon this video on youtube of a fight Gintoki had with Hijikata on a roof which ended with Gin winning.This is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MK6e1RBck9w). Anyway, does anyone know what episode is this fight from?

Thanks for the help as always :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is Gintama episode 9

You can search for Gintama episode 9 on a video site.

Reference 
[Gintama Wikia](http://gintama.wikia.com/wiki/Trivia)